# CSS keyframe for cycling through text

Tags: css, css-animations

I wanted a non-javascript solution to cycle through different text phrases. I found [one tutorial](https://simplernerd.com/js-cycle-text/) that I could not get to work. Here is the solution given:

For a span element:

```
<span id="cycle"></span>
```

Use the following styling:

```
#cycle:after {
    -webkit-animation: cycle 4s infinite; /* Safari 4+ */
    -moz-animation: cycle 4s infinite; /* Fx 5+ */
    -o-animation: cycle 4s infinite; /* Opera 12+ */
    animation: cycle 4s infinite; /* IE 10+, Fx 29+ */
  }
}
@keyframes cycle {
  0% {
    content: "Corgi";
  }
  33% {
    content: "Shih Tzu";
  }
  66% {
    content: "Pug";
  }
  100% {
    content: "Dachshund";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I made several changes to the above code to get this to work.
First, in the `#cycle:after` block, I updated the properties to specify the name of the animation and removed the browser specific properties. I also added `content:"";` to initiate the content. Note that `:after` is needed to change `content` (places the new text after the current text in the element).

```
#cycle:after {
    animation-name:cycle;
    animation-duration: 4s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    content: "";
  }
}
```

The existing `@keyframes` block will kind of work, but the timing doesn't seem to be what they were shooting for. Adjustments to the percents result in each phrase showing for one second.

```
@keyframes cycle {
  0% {
    content: "Corgi";
  }
  25% {
    content: "Shih Tzu";
  }
  50% {
    content: "Pug";
  }
  75% {
    content: "Dachshund";
  }
  100% {
    content: "Corgi";
  }
}
```

Without the final "Corgi" at 100% it will show no text for a moment.